# *_ and Unpacking Elements from Iterables of Arbitrary Length in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, naming-conventions, iterable-unpacking

```
record= ('ACME', 50, 123.45, (12, 18, 2012))
name, *_, (*_, year) = record 
print(name)
>>>'ACME'
print (year)
>>> 2012
print (*_)
>>> 12 18
```

So i started reading about unpacking tuples, lists and dictionaries. It said

> Sometimes you might want to unpack values and throw them away. You
>   can’t just specify a bare * when unpacking, but you could use a common
>   throwaway variable name, such as _ or ign(ignored)

I didn't quite understand, so I tried to understand by visualizing my code on [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com) but it didn't really "throwaway" the values assigned to *_, also I am unable to access the data " 50, 123.45". I am just starting, so please bear with me cause I am having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: "also I am unable to access the data " 50, 123.45"" - if you wanted to access that data, then *why did you use `*_`*?

Comment: i wanted to see what *_ actually does.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52208981/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Use a common throwaway variable name" is the clue.  `*_` is unpacking (`*`) into a variable named `_`.  The only thing that makes `_` "throwaway" is that it is generally ignored.  However, if you don't ignore it, it won't be a throwaway!

If you want to unpack multiple pieces, and still be able to access them separately, use different variable names.  Your example:

```
>>> record= ('ACME', 50, 123.45, (12, 18, 2012))
>>> name, *_, (*_, year) = record
>>> print(name,year,*_)
ACME 2012 12 18
```

assigns the variable `_` twice, so the later-assigned data `12,18` overwrites the earlier-assigned data `50,123.45`.  By contrast, consider:

```
>>> name, *_a, (*_b, year) = record
>>> print(*_a)
50 123.45                 <-- the data you mentioned
>>> print(*_b)
12 18
```

In this example, `_a` and `_b` are separate variables that hold separate contents.  The assignment

```
name, *_a, (*_b, year) = record
```

is exactly the same as

```
name, *extra1, (*extra2, year) = record
```

but with different names.  Again, nothing about `_` itself is magical.